# Delete nodes on multiple lines with a difference or exclusion from shape

Tags: inkscape, vector

I'm struggling to find a solution to my problem. Attached is a simplified representation of what I'm trying to achieve.

Basically I need to trim a large number of cloned lines, as to limit my file size. I've tried all options between 'difference' and 'break apart' in 'path menu', but no luck.

Can anyone advise? Is it a matter of setting the colors and/or opacity? Layer order? I tried many combinations, but nothing.

I want to make clear that I know of clipping and masking, but that doesn't get rid of the nodes, and the file is way too large.[image]

Comment: If the lines are still cloned, why not trimming the original one? If the lines are separate paths, have you tried to combine them and using the difference on the whole? Or, maybe, have you tried to use the [eraser tool](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Eraser.html)?

Comment: So I never thought about not unclamping the clones and editing the first one as a precursor for all of the other ones. Not sure why, but unclamping function was not available in my last few tries. Will deff check it.
Difference didn't work as mentioned above. 
Will look into eraser, but we're talking possibly 10k nodes...
Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Try some tests and refine the question if necessary.

Comment: The method of editing clones did work, so I'm kinda one step farther. It's a very cumbersome project, though, due to so many paths. I' thinking some scripting would be a better solution.

Comment: Maybe. Scripting is always useful. If you have reached a satisfactory solution to your question, please feel free to write the answer yourself and mark it as correct.

Comment: Sure. Someone suggested https://two.js.org/ for web, which is what I'm trying to do, so if I can figure it out, I'll post.

Comment: It all depends on your programming skills. You can also write code snippets to generate xml code with part of the drawings to be inserted in the SVG file.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what is it that you mean with code snippets? Maybe a link to some example?

Comment: SVG is XML based, you can proceed like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58358939/182588). See also [svgpp](https://github.com/svgpp/svgpp), [SVG.js](https://svgjs.com), [simple-svg](https://github.com/adishavit/simple-svg), [drawSvg](https://pypi.org/project/drawSvg/), [svgwrite](https://pypi.org/project/svgwrite/), [Pycairo](https://github.com/pygobject/pycairo), ...